# How to save XML file in PL/SQL database

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I need to store the text of an **XML** file that I already have stored in a location of an FTP, in a field of a table in the database, I am using the package `UTL_FILE` to read files, I am not very clear about the operation of the package and I just start with the topic of procedures in **PL/SQL**. My approach to date is to:

1. Use `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` to open the file.
2. Create an `INSERT` inside procedure to store in a database field

For this I am performing a procedure in **PL/SQL** I do not know if it is the right thing for what I am requiring

```
    DECLARE

    file BFILE;
    clob CLOB;
    FILE UTL_FILE.file_type;
    TEXT VARCHAR2(32767);
    L_CONN UTL_TCP.connection;
    CODE SPRCMNT.MNTCODE%TYPE;
    TEXT      MNT.MNT_TEXT%TYPE;
    TEXT_NAR  MNT.MNT_TEXT_NAR%TYPE;

BEGIN

    L_CONN := FTP.LOGIN('000.00.000.00', '00', '*********', '*********');
    FTP.ASCII(P_CONN => L_CONN);
    FTP.GET(P_CONN => L_CONN, p_from_file => '/xml_file/file.xml', p_to_dir => 'UPLOAD_DIR',  p_to_file => 'file.xml');
    ftp.logout(l_conn);

    VFILE := UTL_FILE.fopen('UPLOAD_DIR', 'file.xml', 'R', 4000);

    LOOP
        BEGIN
            UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(VFILE, TEXT, 32767);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEXT);
            INSERT INTO SPRETA (
                     ID,
                     CODE,
                     TEXT,
                     TEXT_NAR,
                     DATE)
                            VALUES('15218',
                                   '15',
                                   TEXT,
                                   TEXT_NAR,
                                   SYSDATE)
                                   RETURN TEXT_NAR INTO l_clob;

         l_bfile := BFILENAME ('UPLOAD', 'file.xml');
         dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile, dbms_lob.FILE_READONLY );
         dbms_lob.loadfromfile( l_clob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength(l_bfile) );
         dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );
         COMMIT;

         EXCEPTION 
            WHEN OTHERS THEN EXIT;
                   dbms_output.put_line('Error al cargar el archivo');  

        END;
    END LOOP;

    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(FILE);

END;
```

Where it is `CMTT_CODE` going to save by default the value 15, `TEXT` save the name of the **XML** file and `TEXT_NAR` all the content, I mean all the **XML** text in the table `MNT`

I still can't insert all the **XML** text in `TEXT_NAR` the table field `MNT`.

I am trying to adhere to my keep it simple philosophy but I am new to all this and would really appreciate some feedback on the best way to do it.

The main error is that it does not save the **XML** name and what the **XML** file contains in its corresponding fields

Comment: you cannot load a file from a local client to the database.  The file needs to reside on the database server.

Comment: PL/SQL runs in the context of the database server therefore it can only access files that the server has access to..

Comment: Is this a process that will happen once or many times?
 Are you able to access the database server to put the file(s) there?
 Why / why not?

Comment: What is your client OS? Do you have bash/cygwin installed?

Comment: You've changed the question substantially - that doesn't seem very fair to the people who answered the original version, it would probably have been better to ask a new question for FTP. Anyway.... in the code you posted you don't ever assign values to `p_text` or `p_text_nar` - what are you expecting those to contain? Also why are looping and getting lines from the XML and storing them individually - don't you want the entire XML document stored as a single value?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be stored code in a single line

Comment: For the old version [you could have used SQL\*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/how-to-load-XML-data.html#GUID-B94D42C1-A20A-457A-8427-C01E39788EA1) from your PC. Are you still actually FTPing from your PC; and if so, are you set on using PL/SQL?

Comment: Yes, I am still using UTL_FTP

Comment: OK... can you include your table structure (i.e. the column data types) in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it's true that the cleanest way to do this is to have the XML data file sent to the database server and use UTL_FILE to load and process, with the right tools you can go some way to bridging that client/server gap.

The method outlined below relies on client scripting to constructing a SQL*Plus script that initialises a CLOB variable with the XML data in a anonymous block, which then facilitates the use of that variable is SQL.

The example below is in bash - if you have bash or Cygwin install on your client (WIndows), or your client is Linux/MacOS, this might help you. If not, maybe someone could write a DOS BAT/Powershell equivalent.

The idea is to construct a script with the XML data presented as a variable in an anonymous PLSQL block and then pass onto a stored procedure.

Here is the bash script the_script.sh:

```
XML_FILE=${1}   # File containing XML to load

SQL_SCRIPT=the_script.sql   # script we will construct to do the work

# Start constructing teh PLSQL blcok

cat <<EOF > ${SQL_SCRIPT}

declare
   vx_xml XMLTYPE;
   vc_xml CLOB ;
begin
   vc_xml := '';   
EOF

cat ${XML_FILE} | fold -80 -s | sed "s/^/      vc_xml := vc_xml || '/" | sed "s/$/';/" >> ${SQL_SCRIPT}


cat <<EOF >> ${SQL_SCRIPT}

   vx_xml := XMLTYPE(vc_xml);
   call_the_stored_proc(vx_xml); -- A strored procedure to process the XML data as required
end;
/

EOF

cat ${SQL_SCRIPT}

cat <<EOF > sqlplus -S /nolog

conn un/pw@db

@${SQL_SCRIPT}

quit

EOF
```

Run this as follows:

`bash the_script.sh the_source_data.xml`

Comment: I tried to do with the `UTL_FILE` package, but I still can't insert the data in the table

Comment: The question is now quite different to the original, so my answer above no longer applies.

Answer (score 2):

As you're in a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) and [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) environment, here's a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and [sqlcl](/questions/tagged/sqlcl) solution.

given `some.xml` file like.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<listitem someattribute='thingOne'>content One</listitem>
<listitem someattribute='thingTwo'>content Two</listitem>
<listitem someattribute='thingThree'>content Three</listitem>
</root>
```

and a table `MYTABLE` like:

```
Name           Null?    Type               
-------------- -------- ------------------ 
COLUMNONE               VARCHAR2(25)         
COLUMNTWO               VARCHAR2(25)
```

I'll use a PowerShell script (xml2csv.ps1) like:

```bsh
#read from file
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content -Path some.xml

#Walk through the records
$inputFile.root.ChildNodes | 
    # re-map to column names using ScriptBlock(s)
    Select-Object @{Name=’columnOne’; Expression={$_.someattribute}},@{Name=’columnTwo’; Expression={$_.'#text'}} |
        # write out CSV file
        Export-Csv -Path some.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding:UTF8
```

Run this as `powershell.exe xml2csv.ps1`

Load the database by using SQLcl (download from https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html or included in SQL Developer) and run the LOAD command (https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/09/sqlcl-and-the-load-csv-command/).

Start a session `sql.exe myuser/mypassword@MYDATABASE` and execute:

```sql
LOAD MYTABLE some.csv
```